# Как правильно обработать HibernateException?

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, исключения

Вопрос может и глупый, но я на нём застопорился и не знаю как быть. В общем, есть у меня метод `save` в классе `ItemDAO`, собственно вот он:

```
Item save(Item item){

        Transaction transaction = null;
        try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()){
            transaction = session.getTransaction();

            transaction.begin();

            session.save(item);

            transaction.commit();

        }catch (HibernateException e){

            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }

            System.err.println("Operation failed");
            throw e;
        }
        return item;
    }
```

В блоке `catch` я отлавливаю ошибку и пробрасываю её дальше в класс `ItemService` :

```
Item save(Item item){

        try {

            itemDAO.save(item);

        }catch (HibernateException e){
            System.err.println("Operation failed");
            throw e;
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Потом в `ItemController` и из него в `MyServlet` и уже в нём вывожу пользователю сообщение `"Operation failed"` через `response`:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        try {
            controller.save(mappingObject(req));

            resp.getWriter().println("Object saved successfully");

        } catch (BadRequestException e) {

            resp.getWriter().println(e);

        }catch (HibernateException e){

            resp.getWriter().println("Operation failed");
        }
    }
```

Для того, чтобы протестировать, в методе `save` в классе `ItemDAO`, перед сохранением в базу, присваиваю входящему объекту значение `null`. Запускаю `Postman` и отправляю из него `Post` запрос. И в консоли `Postman` получаю не `Operation failed` , а вот такую простыню:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже всякие разные вариации пробовал, но видимо всё не то. Подскажите "нубу", как вывести в консоль `Postmаn` (это будет ответ для пользователя) строку `Operation failed` ?

Comment: На скрине явно видно, что возникает `IllegalArgumentException` , а в коде эта ошибка нигде не обрабатывается, обработайте ее.

Comment: MrFylypenko, это я явно, перед сохранением объекта, присвоил ему значение `null` и поэтому она появляется, хотя я её сразу и не заметил

Comment: MrFylypenko, я наверное не правильно понимаю какие ошибки отлавливает `HibernateException` ...

Comment: [Есть документация по HibernateException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html) , найдите для Вашей версии hibernate. Там в разделе `Known Subclasses` перечислены все ошибки, которые отлавливает `HibernateException` . Ошибки  `IllegalArgumentException` там нет, поэтому она не отлавливается указанными catch, и пробрасывается выше. `IllegalArgumentException` и `HibernateException` наследуется от `RuntimeException` и если хотите перехватить все ошибки, то в catch укажите `RuntimeException`.

Comment: MrFylypenko, спасибо за помощь... действительно я не отлавливал `IllegalArgumentException`, и в `catch` не правильно пробрасывал ошибку выше. Я использовал `throw e`, а надо было `throw new ...Exception("description");`.